# Why does my OpenFileDialog not allow me to step Into or Over it?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-debugging, openfiledialog

I am trying to open a file this way:

```
private void btnDoc1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string sDoc1 = string.Empty;
    using (OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog())
    {
        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            sDoc1 = openFileDialog1.FileName;
        }
    }
    . . .
```

...but when I put a break on the "using" line and then hit either F10 or F11 upon reaching it, the OpenFileDialog is not displayed for me to select a file.

Why not? What do I need to do?

By the way, I actually have to select "Step Over" and "Step Into" from the menu each time rather than hitting the hotkey. Using the hotkeys don't work. Doing so brings up some funky-looking tiny control that looks like a volume control or something.

Comment: Wouldn't you have to advance twice? `ShowDialog` is the part that shows it.

Comment: May be it is showing behind your visual studio? Just to be sure, please minimize your visual studio when you are passing that line.

Comment: I thought of that; but never saw the dialog.

Comment: Are you running the debug version of your program? It sounds stupid, but it happened to me I had the vesion on release and then your program is optimized and debugging does not really work fine.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't set it to that. Is it set that way by default? Where is this setting located?